# Can anyone tell me what type of snake this is?

Tags: snake

I found this snake in my garden and I'm wondering what type of snake it is! It was around 1 metre long and I'm in Lincolnshire UK.

[image]

Comment: It was around 1 metre long and I'm in Lincolnshire UK

Comment: With all due respect, it's fairly common knowledge that there are (essentially) only 4 native snakes in the UK: the adder, grass snake, smooth snake and barred grass snake. If you see a snake in the UK, chances are it's one of them.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a [Barred Grass Snake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barred_grass_snake), *Natrix helvetica*. There are only a few snakes naturally found in the UK, and the Grass Snake matches the size, color, and pattern (bars on the sides but not on the back). The "*N. helvetica*" designation is [relatively new](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-40853286), 2017, following genetic testing that showed that the previous name of *Natrix natrix* was not correct. "The newly distinguished snake is grey, not olive green like the N. natrix and does not have the same bright yellow collar."

- [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4sZI0xO75Ro)
- [Stock photo from Alarmy](https://www.alamy.com/grass-snake-colubrid-colubrids-natrix-natrix-helvetica-snake-snakes-reptile-reptiles-general-view-protected-endangered-image279852215.html)
- Publication describing geographical distribution: [Phylogeography and taxonomy of the barred grass snake (Natrix helvetica), with a discussion of the subspecies category in zoology](http://www.senckenberg.de/files/content/forschung/publikationen/vertebratezoology/vz68-3/07_vertebrate_zoology_68_3_kindler_269-281.pdf). Figure 1 (below) includes a photo

[image]

Smooth Snake is another possibility but seems much less likely to me.

> Smooth snakes are slender and normally grow to around 55 cm (2 ft). They are grey or grey-brown with **darker markings along their back** and usually a 'butterfly' shape on the top of their head. They are **very rare in the UK** but can be found in heathland habitats in Surrey. It would be **very unusual to find a smooth snake in your garden**. They are very secretive and would normally be found underneath objects.

--[Which snake is it?](https://www.aylesburyvaledc.gov.uk/sites/default/files/page_downloads/Snakes.pdf)
 (My emphasis)

Answer (score 0):

## Smooth Snake.

1 Metre long is a bit large for this species, but it is in that range and it is where you live.

> Both sexes grow to an average length of about 60 cm (24 in) to 75 cm (30 in). Two specimens measuring 83 cm (33 in) have been recorded in Sweden, as well as one in Russia that was 92 cm (36 in).
>
> [...]
>
> [image]
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Smooth Snake - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_snake)</sub>

Here is another picture of the snake, which seems almost identical to yours.

[image]